# Join two queries / Divide Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to divide first query by second query to get the result,

First query is

```
select count(*)*100 from event.enrollment e 
inner join event.schedule s on 
 e.ScheduleId=s.ScheduleId 
 where s.EventId=@eventId
```

and
Second Query

```
 select MaxCapacity from [Event].schedule s where  s.eventid=@eventId
```

Comment: check out the union statement

Comment: Neil where bro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just divide the values:

```
select count(e.ScheduleId)*100.0 / max(s.MaxCapacity)
from  event.schedule s left join
      event.enrollment e 
      on e.ScheduleId = s.ScheduleId 
where s.EventId = @eventId;
```

The `max()` for the capacity is simply so the aggregation works.

The `count(e.ScheduleId)` is to count the number of matching rows in enrollment.

The `100.0` is because SQL Server does integer division and that is likely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Without further knowledge about your database and relations - but the subquery should work anyway:

```
select 
count(*)*100 
/
(select MaxCapacity from [Event].schedule s where  s.eventid=@eventId)
from event.enrollment e 
inner join event.schedule s on 
 e.ScheduleId=s.ScheduleId 
 where s.EventId=@eventId
```

But you can probably use the data from joined `event.schedule` table.